# Python Matplotlib Buttons widgets and SpanSelector events

Tags: python, matplotlib, events, callback

I am trying to write a program that switches between signals by clicking "previous" and "next" button, and at the same time gives the possibility to select and save part of the plot. This is what I got so far:

```
%matplotlib tk

itera = list(range(1, 100))      

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.grid()
plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.2)

t = time_axis
s = signal[0]        # first signal in the plot

l, = plt.plot(time, s, lw=2)           # first plot
plt.xlabel('Time (s)')
plt.ylabel('Acceleration')
plt.title('Plot batches')

############### Buttons widget  ####################

class Index(object):
    ind = 0

    def next(self, event):
        self.ind += 1
        i = self.ind % len(itera)
        ydata = signal[i]     
        l.set_ydata(ydata)
        plt.draw()

    def prev(self, event):
        self.ind -= 1
        i = self.ind % len(itera)
        ydata = signal[i] 
        l.set_ydata(ydata)
        plt.draw()

callback = Index()

axprev = plt.axes([0.7, 0.05, 0.1, 0.075])
axnext = plt.axes([0.81, 0.05, 0.1, 0.075])
bnext = Button(axnext, 'Next')
bnext.on_clicked(callback.next)

bprev = Button(axprev, 'Previous')
bprev.on_clicked(callback.prev)


###############  Select part of the port  ####################

def onselect(xmin, xmax):
    x = time_axis
    y = signal[callback.ind % len(itera)]
    indmin, indmax = np.searchsorted(x, (xmin, xmax))
    indmax = min(len(x) - 1, indmax)

    thisx = x[indmin:indmax]
    thisy = y[indmin:indmax]

    # save
    np.savetxt("text", np.c_[thisx, thisy])


def fun_with_spanselector_inside():
    span = SpanSelector(ax, onselect, 'horizontal', useblit=True,
                        rectprops=dict(alpha=0.5, facecolor='red') )
    return span

span = fun_with_spanselector_inside()

plt.show()
```

At the moment, I don't know how to update the y signal in the onselect function accordingly to the button that has been pressed.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

> **UPDATE:**

I have updated my code and soled the question above.
Now, I don't know how to select multiple parts of the same plot and save them to different files. At the moment the file 'text' gets updated every time and I lose the data every time I select a new area of the plot.

Can someone help me with this?

I am new to python and especially with matplotlib so sorry I am asking something basic.

Thanks

Comment: The signal that is currently shown should be `signal[callback.ind % len(itera)]`, right? So you can use it inside of `onselect` for whatever purpose you wish. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Yes, that was correct. Thank you very much. I have now updated my question since the problems are never ending